# How to dynamically copy multiple datasets from a Google BigQuery project using Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: google-bigquery, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, lookup-tables

Is it possible to dynamically copy all datasets from a BigQuery Project to Azure Synapse Analytics, then dynamically copy all tables within each dataset? I know we can dynamically copy all tables within a BigQuery dataset reference to this answered question [Loop over of table names ADFv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57664561/loop-over-of-table-names-adfv2), but is there a way to do it at the project level with the lookup activity to loop through all datasets? Is there a way to do a `SELECT *` to the datasets?

```
SELECT
*
FROM
gcp_project_name.dataset_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
```

According to Microsoft's [Lookup activity in Azure Data Factory and Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity), this only reaches the dataset level.
I also tried just putting in the GCP's project name into the Lookup activity's query, but it did not work, ref [Understanding the "Not found: Dataset ### was not found in location US" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72273707/understanding-the-not-found-dataset-was-not-found-in-location-us-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- This can be done using two-level pipeline. I tried to repro this and below is the approach.
- Take a **lookup activity** and take the Google big query as source dataset. In Query text box, enter the below query.

```sql
SELECT schema_name
FROM  `project_name`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
```

This query will list the datasets in the project.

[image]

- Add a for-each activity next to the lookup activity. In for-each settings' item , type `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` as a dynamic content.

[image]

- Then inside for-each activity, take another lookup activity with same big Query dataset as  source dataset. Type the below query as a dynamic content.

```sql
SELECT
*
FROM
gcp_project_name.dataset_name.@{item().schema_name}.TABLES
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
```

This will give list of all tables within each dataset.

Since you cannot nest a for-each inside for-each in ADF, you can design a two-level pipeline where the outer pipeline with the outer ForEach loop iterates over an inner pipeline with the nested loop.

Refer the NiharikaMoola-MT's answer on this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684969/nested-foreach-in-adf-azure-data-factory) for Nested foreach in ADF.